# How to remove extra space above the figure

Tags: spacing

This is tex file

```
Thus, speculatively, higher-order antibunching might play a role superior to usual antibunching. Note that such a prominence of higher-order antibunching was discovered for the first time in [22] for two-mode coherent states.
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Hinh2.jpg}
\centering
\caption{Single-mode $l$ th-order antibunching of mode $a, A_{a;l}$, as a function of the order $l$ at $r = 4$ and $p = q = 2$ (circles) and $p = q = 4$ (triangles).}
\end{figure}
\end{flushleft}
```

And the output pdf is:

[image]

There is a unexpected extra space above the figure. Please help me how to remove it.

Comment: Do a quick compile of \documentclass{standalone}\begin{document} \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Hinh2.jpg} \end{document}  This will let you see exactly how much `white` space surrounds the figure.   Then we need a MWE which shows the behavior in a minimum context which displays the problem.   I suspect that this is probably caused by what is occurring before this figure.

Comment: It looks like your figure is on a page with nothing else. Do you want it to be at the top of an otherwise empty page? If you add more text the figure will move up on its own.

Comment: Put this if you want the picture in a specific place  \begin{figure}[h!] maybe that solves your problem

Comment: the `flushleft` there is not changing the alignment just adding spurious vertical space at the point the figure was before it floated.

Comment: @Very23 don't use `h!` that usually generates a warning that it has been changed to `!ht`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\centering` can also be used later. The end of paragraph is the latest point. Here, the settings are read for typesetting the paragraph. But it is more clear and easier to read, if it is put at the beginning.

Comment: `JPEG` is a very bad choice for drawings. Vector graphics as possible in `EPS` or `PDF` is much better. If bitmap images cannot be avoided, then saving as `PNG` is better than a lossy image format with weaknesses on sharp edges.

Comment: If the image already contains the space, then it can be removed by an image program such as `gimp` or the lossless command line program `jpegtran`. Or the plot can be redrawn with LaTeX package `pgfplots`, the program `gnuplot` or other tools capable of vector output.